# Varnish: what does regsuball do?

Tags: caching, varnish

All that I found about regsuball - it's description from docs: https://book.varnish-software.com/3.0/VCL_Basics.html#vcl-functions . But it still not clear for me what happens inside regsuball function. How does passed params (str, regex, sub) used? Is there a sandbox to test regsuball function online? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Syntax

The `regsuball()` function will perform a regular expression match on a string and replace all occurences with another pattern.

```
regsuball(string, regex, sub)
```

- The `string` argument is your input.
- The `regex` argument is the regular expression you're using to match what you're looking for in the input string.
- The `sub` argument is what the input string will be substituted with.

### Example

The following example will look for cookies named `original-cookie-123`, where the numeric suffix could be any number. It replaces that with `modified-cookie-123`:

```
regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "original-cookie-([0-9+])", "modified-cookie-\1");
```

Imagine using passing the following cookie to Varnish:

```
Cookie: a=1; b=2; original-cookie-1=bla; c=3; original-cookie-2=test
```

The result after the find/replace would be:

```
Cookie: a=1; b=2; modified-cookie-1=bla; c=3; modified-cookie-2=test
```

> Whereas `regsub()` matches and replaces the first occurrence of the pattern, `regsuball()` replaces all occurrences.

### Sandbox

If you want to test `regsuball()` in a sandbox, the easiest way is by running [`varnishtest`](http://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/varnishtest.html) on a testcase. Here's an example:

```
varnishtest "Regsuball sandbox"

varnish v1 -vcl+backend { 
    vcl 4.1;

    backend default none;

    sub vcl_recv {
        if (req.http.Cookie) {
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "original-cookie-([0-9+])", "modified-cookie-\1");
            return (synth(200, req.http.Cookie));
        } 
        return (synth(400, "No cookie found"));
    }

    sub vcl_synth {
        set resp.http.Content-Type = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
        set resp.body = req.http.Cookie;
        return (deliver);
    }

} -start

client c1 {
    txreq -hdr "Cookie: a=1; b=2; original-cookie-1=bla; c=3; original-cookie-2=test"
    rxresp
    expect resp.body == "a=1; b=2; modified-cookie-1=bla; c=3; modified-cookie-2=test"
} -run
```

This test case uses the exact example mentioned earlier. After the find and replace, the VCL code in this test case will synthetically return the resulting value as output. There's no need for a backend server, all output is generated by the VCL code.

Running the test case, assuming it is stored in `test.vtc` can be done using the following command:

```
varnishtest test.vtc
```

You can also run this test case isolated within a Docker container. Just run the following command to bootstrap a Varnish Docker container and run the test:

```
docker run --rm  --name varnishtest  -v $(pwd)/test.vtc:/etc/varnish/test.vtc varnish:stable varnishtest /etc/varnish/test.vtc
```